Model Performance Varying Greatly
I have built an XGBoost model that performs rather weirdly across months...
I trained the model on a heavily imbalanced dataset (1:40 000), which I undersampled to (1:500).
The model performance (Recall-Precision-F1) is as follows (predicting...):

Train Set (1 year data): 100%-100%-100%
Test Set (1 month data, e.g. June): 29%-4%-7%
Out-of-Time Testing 1 (e.g. July): 33%-12%-18%
OOT Testing 2 (e.g. Aug): 10%-1%-2%
OOT Testing 3 (e.g. Sep): 77%-7%-12%

Note that generally, there are only ~10 positive instances per month (e.g. in Train Set, I had 127 instances, while in Test-OOTs, there are ~10-15 instances per month, with July having anomalously high 43 instances). There are generally ~200-300k cases with only ~10 positive cases per month, and my model seems to consistently only flag only ~100-150 cases each month.
At first I thought that the model suffers from a classic overfitting (indicated from its Train performance). But then, for some reason, it can achieve fairly-okay performance on July and Sept. (in my specific case, those performance are already considered good enough). Moreover, the model seems to achieve quite a high precision on July (12% precision; again, good enough; this means that I can flag only ~100 cases out of hundred thousands of cases that month, with FP=~90 and TP=~10 thus achieving ~10% precision)
I was wondering if anyone has any thoughts on this? Am I seeing an overfitting case? Or does this "performance fluctuations" simply due to the nature of the problem? (i.e. if I only have ~10 cases per month, of course just by detecting 1 extra case, I can 'raise' my recall by 10%).

There might be seasonality in your data. See Why should we remove seasonality from a time series?
